# Blender 2.83 Displacement - Cycles and Eevee

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, eevee-render-engine, displacement

I have problems with working on displacement node. So there I have setup of nodes.

[image: Node Setup]

Cycles Render
[image: Cycles Render]

Eevee Render
[image: Eevee Render]

On Cycles there's some error in displacement. I tried to adjust displacement with displacement node(also i have enabled Displacement and bump in options). Used displacement + normal map node still the same result. Displacement looks like it moved to right top side instead of being in the same place as headlight. On Eevee it's looking good.
What is the solution to solve this because I have no idea?

Comment: Can you provide the portion of the file that's showing the error, so that it can be reviewed? I attempted to recreate your node setup, but it's uh... a little... all over the place. Meanwhile, off the top of my head, try attaching a mapping node to the image texture, and a texture coordinate node to that mapping node (so "Texture coordinate" -> "Mapping" -> "Image texture", all via "Vector")

Answer (score 3):

The reason there's no error in the displacement in EEVEE is that there is no displacement in EEVEE.

So, if you like what you see there, the simplest solution is to unplug the displacement. But that's not an explanation of what's happening.

If a vector is plugged straight into the Displacement input of a *Material Output* node without going through a *Displacement* node first, what you get is a displacement of the shading-points by that vector, in Blender Units, in Object Space. (That is, along the object's local axes, and taking the object's scale transform into account).

You can get the feel of that by plugging a *Combine XYZ* node into the Displacement input, and playing with the numbers.

It looks as if you would probably want simple displacement along the normals of your surface here -  there are no undercuts. So, if you did want to displace the inside surface of the glass, you would have a UV map of the lens which separated the inside and outside surfaces, and, covering the region of the map representing the inside surface, have an image which would serve as a height map, with 0 values interpreted as no displacement, and 1 values as full displacement.

You would then plug that map into the Height input of a Displacement node, and in turn, plug the Displacement node onto the Material Output.

Comment: Used only bump into normal map input and got similar result as in Eevee with "displacement" as you said that's not a displacement.

Comment: @PulpiK been doing some tests, here... since you can't see a displaced profile, everything interesting in this case is dealt with by bump-mapping. Refraction is pretty much  as good. it only needs the normals twisting. And it's _much_ cheaper.